# On a French car, what does "eclair" mean, please?

Tags: sens, abréviations

I soon hope to buy a Simca, with "eclair" as one of the dashboard controls. Is this a reference to the lights?

Comment: Could you please provide us more details and/or a picture of it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is indeed a short form of *éclairage* used on some Simca dashboards.

Here an Ariane 4 SL 1959 model dashboard:

[image]

and here is an excerpt from an add of the Vedette V8 1956 model:

[image]

The buttons labels are:
- CHAUF : *Chauffage* (heater) on the Vedette V8
- CLIMAT : *Climatisation* (air conditioning) on the Ariane 4
- START : *Starter* (choke)
- ECLAIR: *Éclairage* (lights)
- AVERT : *Avertisseur* (horn)
- ESS GL: *Essuie glace* (wiper)
- DEMAR : *Démarreur* (starter)

Photo credits: https://simca67etanciennes.jimdo.com/simc-adh%C3%A9rents/patrick/ and http://www.auto-pub.net/Simca/Simca_Vedette_56/Simca_Vedette_6.jpg

Comment: Est-ce l'éclairage dans l'habitacle ou une référence aux phares ?

Comment: @Jardindefrostedflakes Je pense qu'il s'agit des phares. Les interrupteurs d'éclairage intérieur étaient probablement accolés aux lampes.

Comment: I would like to express my sincere thanks for your responses, which I now understand. My VERY limited French led me to assume that, as eclair meant "lightning" that this button was somehow linked to charging the battery. That you used actual pictures from my favourite car, the Ariane, means a great deal. I appreciate your efforts and thank you all.